# How to deal with fail chain on Ethereum?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, go-ethereum, geth

I am building decentralized application which grabs data from blockchain to mysql database.

**I'm not sure, but I guess** it is possible that one part of Ethereum network accepts newly mined transaction X and another part accepts mined transaction Y. Some time later one of this transactions should be accepted by full chain and other transaction should fail.

If my node gets in wrong chain I will have incorrect data on my mysql database. And it will be hard to revert database back.

How to deal correctly with these types of conflicts? Should I grab data only after certain number of confirmations (for example 5 or 10)? Or there is another approach?

Comment: Your question may be more suited to another StackExchange site. For questions related to Bitcoin and other cryptocurrencies, please ask on the [**Bitcoin StackExchange**](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com) instead. For questions *specific* to Ethereum, please ask on the [**Ethereum StackExchange**](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com) instead. For further information, please refer to the documentation regarding what is considered '[**on-topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)' for StackOverflow, and what questions [**shouldn't be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) here.

Comment: This question may be more suited to the [**Ethereum StackExchange**](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com) :)

Comment: Thanks for info, I asked this question on stackexchange: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/36456/how-to-deal-with-fail-chain-on-ethereum